# Convergence of Iterated Mapping to Fixed Point

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Consider the following discrete system
\begin{align*}
x_{t+1} &= (1 + \alpha(1-x_t)) \cdot (1-\alpha y_t) \cdot x_t,\\
y_{t+1} &= (1 + \alpha(1-y_t)) \cdot (1-\alpha x_t) \cdot y_t,
\end{align*}
with initial values $0 < y_0 < x_0 < 1$ and $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. Based on simulations I believe that there is convergence to the fixed point $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}~(x_t, y_t) = (1, 0)$ and similarly if $x_0 < y_0$ then $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}~(x_t, y_t) = (0, 1)$, but I am having trouble proving this and would appreciate any help.

I believe the Jacobian of the map $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(x_{t+1}, y_{t+1}) = F(x_t, y_t)$ is given by
$$
J(x,y) =
\begin{pmatrix}
(1 + \alpha(1-2x))(1 - \alpha y) & -\alpha x(1 + \alpha(1-x)) \\
-\alpha y(1 + \alpha(1-y)) &(1 + \alpha(1-2y))(1 - \alpha x) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
but $J(x,y)$ does not seem to have operator norm less than $1$ on $[0, 1]\times[0,1]$ so I am not sure if I can show contraction. Are there any other techniques for understanding the behavior of systems of this kind?

Comment: Try to use "contraction principle". That is, if $F(x)$ acts such that $||F(x)-F(y)|| <c||x-y||$ where $c < 1$ then iteration of $F$ converge to its fixed point. Here $F$ works between $R^2$ and one would hope that $c$ is maximum of its derivative, i.e. matrix norm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Salcio, but as I mention in my edited question, I don't think that the maximum derivative is less than 1.

Comment: look into Brouwer's fixed point theorem. If you could show that your domain is invariant, then you have a fixed point. Although, you need to have convex, compact domain.

Comment: @dezdichado, thanks but I already know that there are fixed points e.g. (1, 0) and (0, 1), however I am trying to show convergence to a particular fixed point.

Comment: some observations: $x_t>y_t$ holds always for the $x_0 >y_0$ case and vice versa. Simulation suggests $x_t$ will be eventually increasing and $y_t$ will be eventually decreasing, which if proven should be sufficient. The behavior somewhat depends on $x_0,y_0, \alpha$.